# String Counts from dynamic data sets in Python

Tags: python

My question is very similar to others' here but I haven't found the exact answer I'm looking for so I hope a veteran Python user will be able to further me along.

I'm learning scripting methods for my job but they won't send me to a training center to learn it so my Chief Technical Officer said that I should learn how to create log files from summarized Wireshark collection reports.  I've had great luck in Bash but he wants me to become fluent in Python - without any help or background in scripting/programming this is a difficult task.  I am attempting to essentially grep from the Wireshark report to a new file, giving a count and list of occurences of DNS traffic.  The only thing is in order to be effective, it needs to be able to work using new data sets at every use, otherwise this is a meaningless exercise.

```
>> f1 = open('/home/user/file','r')
>> for line in f1
** if "DNS" in line:
**** print line
```

Two questions:
1) How would I put a count on each DNS occurance?
2) How would I pipe/print to a new txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit more advanced, however, regarding file processing I really like to do some generator pipelining!

```
# this is a generator (an iterable) which only outputs a 
# line containing "DNS" if it was requested in an iteration
# furthermore, the way i use a generator here is called "list comprehension"
dns_lines = ( line for line in open('/home/user/file','r') if "DNS" in line )

# the with-statement uses python's magic-methods to take care of 
# opening and closing the file
with open("output", 'w') as f:
    # enumerate works on generators
    # it enumerates each item that is iterated over
    # a tuple is returned (count, line)
    for count_line in enumerate(dns_lines):
        f.write("%d - %s" % (count_line))
```

More on Generators and file processing here by [David Beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf)

I assumed, that you want to learn a bit more about how powerful python is. Hence, my long comments. :)

// Edit:
A bit more of an explanation regarding what is going to happen here:

- The first line will just generate a generator object.
- The file-reading will start running in the second for-loop.
- As soon as this iteration is started the file will be read until a line containing "DNS" is found.
- A tuple will be created (count, line) and handed over to this very iteration.
- The tuple is written into a file using the format string!
- The next iteration will take place and request the next line, which will start the file-reading again.

I hope this helps!
Generators prevent loading a whole list into the memory and they allow for a lot of neat tricks and pipelined processing. However, there is a lot more to it than you could mention here in this post!

Comment: I really like this answer - it really showcases how Python can achieve so much more with less lines.  Theonly issue that I am having is that it comes up with an IOError: File not open for writing.  I've opened permissions, what could be the culprit?

Comment: @Gregthen00b Thanks :) For me the code is running nicely (the file does not exist yet). Do you have the 'w' flag in the writing passage? I've added that later.

Comment: I missed that and it worked, although I don't have a count in the file.  I itemizes each line nicely though.  Close enough for me! :)

Comment: Where/how long did it take you to learn to do it this way?  I haven't seen this level in any of my books I picked up.  I need to fast-track my learning curve, any advice?

Comment: @Gregthen00b Well it should itemize the file. For me it does that! I just doublechecked now. I have a couple of years experience by just working with it a lot. I really recommend the Beazley read, especially for your purpose! Maybe check something like "advanced python" on google :D I don't know :<

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initialize a new variable to count your items

```
counter = 0

if 'DNS' in line:
    counter += 1

print counter
```

WRT saving your data, you can either do it in python or just print out the data and output it to a file

```
counter = 0
data = []

if 'DNS' in line:
    counter += 1
    data.append(line)

to_s = "\n".join(data)
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
f.write(to_s)
f.close()
```